# PT  Question: Is there a key-command for switching Automation Modes?

Tags: pro-tools, automation, shortcut, pt-quick-keys, keycommand

Hi All,

Quick question, is there a short cut/key command for changing the Automation Mode in PT9?
I was hoping to find it in the reference guide etc. but i can't find it. Hopefully this hasn't been asked before, i searched the forum to no avail.

Anyone able to help me out? It's driving me nuts to have to go to this tiny little button on the left everytime...

Btw i use a novation zero slmk2 and there's no possibility on it either to switch modes...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: just to make clear i want to change from "read" to "touch". not changing the view of automation lanes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to change from read to touch? As long as you don't touch the fader or pot, or any other enabled parameters when writing auto, they behave pretty much the same way.

Comment: Hi Roger, 
I only have an eight bank mixer setup so i am switching a lot between tracks and i don't want to mess up other tracks by riding the wrong fader.... Hope this explains my need for a switch :)

Comment: Arnoud, my $0.02 - try leaving everything write-enabled (e.g. in either touch or latch) always and just practice being careful about what you hit and what you don't when you are making a pass. Leaving stuff in read until you wanted to do anything about it is a habit that an instructor of mine tried to break me out of, it's like buying a car with eight cylinders and using only 2 of them because you're afraid you'll crash if you go too fast. You'll find that you'll have less troubles than you think, and there is always the undo command. That would also solve your issue with needing a hotkey.

Comment: Point taken, i will venture into the unknown, fueled by 8 cylinders! Thanks Luca!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way.

You can COMMAND+CLICK on the LATCH button while recording automation in latch to revert to the (already) recorded automation and exit latch recording.

You can change the automation mode with any supported control surface (ICON, command8, euphonix or any HUI enabled surface).

Comment: Hi Davide,
Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it's not what i hoped for... 
About the HUI enabled surface, i think my Novation should be able to do it... On with my search... 

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternative suggestion. If you go to windows and pull up the automation enable window, you can tell pro tools what parameters to automate. I know it is not as ideal as a key command, but that way you could have all tracks in touch or latch, and then when you want to write some auto -- volume for instance -- you can activate the volume parameter for a second.

Alternatively, if you have an iPad you can check out the various apps that control pro tools. I use Neyrinck's V-Control, and while you go from hitting a tiny button with the mouse to tapping one with your finger, it's still a step.

For what it's worth, it still takes me a moment's concentration to change auto modes when I'm working on a d-command. I might start mixing with everything in touch myself.

Answer (score 0):

the minus sign (not the keypad one) will toggle waveform / volume automation. and 'alt' + '_' will do it for all tracks. and you can ctrl cmd click on any automation enabled parameter to bring up its automation display..

this might be of interest
http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/sep05/articles/keypoints.htm

Comment: Hi Sacha and thanks, but it's not what i meant.. i've edited my question to explain. I will check the link in the meantime!

Comment: ah, sorry about that. 
as far as i know there is no key command for that.
